# Parsing JSON format with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to parse the output from `lsblk`. Since I am doing this from within a script I need the output in a standardized format. Therefore I chose the JSON format as output. Here is the command with some sample output:

```
# lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT -J
{
   "blockdevices": [
      {"name": "sda", "mountpoint": null,
         "children": [
            {"name": "sda1", "mountpoint": "/sda1/mountpoint"},
            {"name": "sda2", "mountpoint": null,
               "children": [
                  {"name": "sda2_mapper", "mountpoint": "/sda2/mountpoint"}
               ]
            },
            {"name": "sda3", "mountpoint": null},
            {"name": "sda4", "mountpoint": null}
         ]
      },
      {"name": "sdb", "mountpoint": null,
         "children": [
            {"name": "sdb1", "mountpoint": "/sdb1/mountpoint"},
            {"name": "sdb2", "mountpoint": null}
         ]
      },
      {"name": "sdc", "mountpoint": null}
   ]
}
```

I want to extract the names of all *innermost* nodes, i.e., the name of all nodes that do not have children. The desired output for the above sample would be:

```
sda1
sda2_mapper
sda3
sda4
sdb1
sdb2
sdc
```

My tool of choice is `jq` which I have only recently discovered. I have tried

```
# jq '.blockdevices[].children[]?.name?'
```

But this only filters the first level of names. I also tried with

```
# jq 'recurse(.name?)'
```

but this returns the entire file.

Is there a way to return only nodes that do not have children, no matter how deep they are nested?

PS: I am capable of implementing the requirement in `bash` or `awk`. I would, however, prefer a solution with a tool like `jq`, which specific purpose is to parse json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the simplest way to do it, but it seems to work:

```
$ jq -r '.blockdevices[] | .. | objects | select(has("children")|not)| .name' tmp.json
sda1
sda2_mapper
sda3
sda4
sdb1
sdb2
sdc
```

It recursively outputs each value found in the JSON, filtering out first anything that is not an object, then any object that has a `children` key. Finally, you can select the `name` value from each remaining object.

Comment: I have a quick follow up question. When I capture the names in an array and with a subsequent call the mountpoints, then the mountpoints will have the same index as their corresponding name, right? The command will not change the order of the original output if I do not add an option like `--sort-keys`, correct?

Comment: Correct. The filter preceding the `.name` filter produces the dictionaries containing both the `name` and `mountpoint` keys.

Answer (score 0):

With your JSON input, the following command:

```
jq '.. | scalars'
```

emits the "leaves", beginning:

```
"sda"
"sda1"
"/sda1/mountpoint"
```

Use the -r (raw output) to strip the quotation marks from strings.